# How can I configure my Oracle tnsnames file location?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, tnsnames

I have Oracle 10g installed on Windows. Currently, my tnsnames file is stored at %ORACLEHOME%\network\admin. However, I want to configure Oracle to look somewhere else for that file.

How can I do this?

Andrew L

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the TNS_ADMIN environment variable to specify a custom location of TNSNAMES.ORA file.
Check this wiki: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/TNS_ADMIN