# Node.js and node-oracle: Problems connecting to Oracle database

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I am writing a Node.js application that pulls data from an Oracle database. The DBA recently migrated the database to another machine, and everything broke.

I've tried re-creating the tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora files. I'm fairly sure that they are correct, because sqlplus can connect to the service just fine. But node-oracle keeps reporting the error: "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified".

This is inexplicable to me. It seems to me that if I have my ORACLE_HOME environment variable set, then both node-oracle and sqlplus should function identically. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried switching to node-db-oracle instead, but it reports the same problem. I'm stumped.

EDIT: This is how I connect:

```
    database = new oracle.Database({
            hostname: Preferences["oracle_host"],  // FQDN of the database
            port: Preferences["oracle_port"],
            user: Credentials["oracle_login"],
            password: Credentials["oracle_password"],
            database: Preferences["oracle_database"]
        });

    connection = database.connect(function(error) {
            if(error) {
                Utilities.logger.error(error);
            }
            else {
                Utilities.logger.info("Connected to Oracle database " + Preferences["oracle_host"]);    
                if(callback) callback.call(this, collection, options);
                connection = this;
            }

        });
```

Comment: The examples for both drivers on github show the hostname etc. defined in the `connect`; so are you sure they even refer to the `tnsnames.ora`? (I've never used either, clearly!) Can you post how you connect?

Comment: OK, so have you updated `oracle_host` in wherever it's getting the `Preferences` values, so that it points to the new server? This is not going through `tnsnames.ora`.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to connect using sqlplus but not using nodejs. I was doing connection like this

```
oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    user          : "test",
    password      : "test",
    connectString : "150.150.50.50:1521/MYDB"
  }
```

The solution that worked for me is to edit sqlnet.ora file and change

```
names.directory_path = (TNSNAMES)
```

to

```
names.directory_path = (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable.

[How can I configure my Oracle tnsnames file location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568342/how-can-i-configure-my-oracle-tnsnames-file-location)

Answer (score 0):

This [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci01int.htm#LNOCI16167) helped me get connected to an oracle database using `node-oracle`. Where I went wrong was I thought the `database` property was the name of the database, but in reality it is the `service_name` (i.e. the `GLOBAL_DBNAME` defined in the `listener.ora` file on the Oracle database, not the `SID_NAME`).

From what I can tell `node-oracle` does not support `tnsnames.ora` as it uses the options to build a connection string such as `//{hostname}:{port}/{database}`.