# Oracle DB connection between two computers

Tags: database, oracle, database-connection, between, tns

I have Computer A , IP = 10.20.30.40 (that store the Oracle Database)
I have Computer B , IP = 10.20.30.50 (with this computer i want to connect)

I have used connection string:
Data Source = LOCALHOST , User = SYSTEM , Password = xxxxx

Its works fine in Computer A. Even i can connect it as
Data Source = 10.20.30.40 , User = SYSTEM , Password = xxxxx

How I can Connect from Computer B - to - Computer A ?

What are the requirements for Computer B Should have??

My tnsnames.ora on Computer A contains info like this:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
```

I'm very new with Oracle, anyone can help some step by step easy guide how to configure this situation?

Comment: Take note of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568342/how-can-i-configure-my-oracle-tnsnames-file-location)

Answer (score 0):

On computer B you will need to use the IP address of computer A (machine running the database).

localhost refers to the local machine.

Comment: OK, so I'm trying to connect with SQL Developer. The connection: Hostname=10.20.30.40, Port: 1521, Servicename=XE. On computer B, I dont have anything, just SQL developer. Can you describe your answer with more details? Thx

Comment: Computer "B" is just a client to the database on computer "A".  SQL Dev is just a GUI client application. As such, it can connect to any database on the network.  In SQL Dev, you define a connection by supplying the name or IP address of the machine running the database, the port number being used by the listener on "A", and the sid or service name (preferrably service name) of the database to which you want to connect.  All of this is simply addressing information of the desired  database so the request can be properly delivered over the network.